# CSS dropdown menu separate first item

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a menu in css using flexbox.
I have already made it responsive so it shrinks from horizontal menu to dropdown menu.

But I struggle separating first menu link from others and putting on the left while the rest are on the right.
As shown in picture I want to put first li the home icon on the left and the rest li items on the right.

Any suggestions?

[menu example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C3kj.jpg)

Comment: Posting question without code is just like repairing the car by seeing the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your image, I think this is a very simple example of what you want.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li:first-child {
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: absolute; /* used only to preserve row alignment */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>home</li>
  <li>whatever 1</li>
  <li>whatever 2</li>
  <li>whatever 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes it works, I didn't expect to be that simple.
I get confused sometimes which is which and where to put the code.
I was using ul:first-item instead li:first-item.

Thanks!